# Ipad View is cutting my table

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

Does anybody know why the Ipad is the only device that do not displaying my Table-Width correct? 
The last Cell of the Tablehead is hidden on the Ipad. On all other devices it looks well.
The resulution is 900px to 1024px
http://goo.gl/WktacL

https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/604aea1088c9c33276451597d508ca6723cbb82d

correct view (all cells are displaying)
[image: correct]
Wrong with Ipad (the last cell isnt there)
[image: Wrong]